# Dealing with IDispatch parameter and COM

Tags: c++, pointers, interface, com

I have a function that return a pointer to an interface pointer via a paramater (project) :

```
CreateProject(std::string str, IDispatch** project);
```

Given two other Interface that implement IDispatch : A and B, is the following code legit given that the real type of project is A. ( I am trying to work with COM VCProjectEngine.CreateProject)

```
A** a;
B** b;

CreateProject("test.vcxproj", a); //should work but I don't know why
CreateProject("test.vcxproj", b); //should not work but I don't know why
```

Can someone explain me how this kind of thing is suppose to work ? I am sorry I am a little bit new with COM objects.

Answer (score 1):

`IDispatch** project` argument typically assumes that you pass a pointer to `IDispatch*` variable, which is to be filled with actual interface pointer:

```
IDispatch* pDispatch;
pDispatch = NULL; // Sanity, optional
CreateProject("test.vcxproj", &pDispatch);
assert(pDispatch != NULL); // Filled by call above
// ...
pDispatch->Release();
```

Since dealing COM interface pointers make you care about proper reference counting, you typically want to use wrapper classes, instead of raw pointers:

```
CComPtr<IDispatch> pDispatch;
CreateProject("test.vcxproj", &pDispatch);
ATLASSERT(pDispatch != NULL);
```

Read up on [`CComPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Having a pointer to the IDispatch interface is not really useful, why I want to do is to have create a project or to load one with this : VCProjectEngine::LoadProject (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcprojectengine.loadproject(v=vs.90).aspx) and then to access the VCProject methods. So it is why I thought that putting a VCProject (that inherit from IDispatch) for parameter it would work.

Comment: Your comment drifts away from the question - it is unclear what you want. You ask about IDispatch, and now you don't want it.

Comment: [Using VCProjectEngine and COM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22283615/using-vcprojectengine-and-com) - Is this the same question?

Comment: I don't want the IDispatch interface, I want the VCProject one (to be able to add file to a project) but the create and load method of VCProjectEngine only take a IDispatch parameter

Comment: Yes It is kinda the same, I will close this one which is unclear.