# Using VCProjectEngine and COM

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2012, com

I am trying to use the COM system for [VCProjectEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine.VCProjectEngine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It is pretty simple to use in C# but I am hitting a wall in native C++.

I am using the COM system and so far I was able to get a pointer to the `VCProjectEngine` interface using the `CoCreateInstance` function.

But now what should I do with this interface? I would like to access the [VCProject interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcproject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to be able to add files to the project. I tried to go with `LoadProject` or `CreateProject` but it takes a `IDispatch` parameter not a `VCProject` one.

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Those methods *return* an IDispatch pointer.  Use QueryInterface() to obtain a VCProject interface pointer.  This is a very basic COM task, do consider that VB.NET or C# will give you a much easier time getting this right.

Comment: Actually it's only guaranteed to return an IUnknown interface pointer,  and QueryInteface() is one of the 3 methods in that interface. But there are better ways than using low-level COM interface function calls.

Comment: Yes but I cannot do that in c# or VB ... Thanks a lot for your hint, should I call it on the IDispatch pointer ?

Comment: I have to do that in native c++ so I think the only way is to go thru COM

Answer (score 0):

Calling COM interfaces from C++ can be done in a number of different ways:

1. "low-level" COM calls using CoCreateInstance and the IUnkown interface
2. ATL (Active-X Template Library) which provides a number of smart pointers and utility functions to make the job a lot easier. Use in conjuction with #import to generate wrapper classes for you.
3. For Windows Store Apps you should use C++/Cx or WRL (Windows Runtime C++ Template Library)

There are many good tutorials and code samples on MSDN.